# How to create folder or key on s3 using AWS SDK for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sdk

I'm using AWS SDK for Node.js to create a folder or key on s3. I searched on google, but I got nothing. Does anybody know how can I create a folder under my bucket with AWS SDK for Node.js?
and how can you check if this folder exists in your bucket already?

if you use `console.aws.amazon.com`, you can create a folder in your bucket easily. it seems I didn't figure it out how to create it with AWS SDK for Node.js?

Answer (score 112):

### AWS SDK v3 Solutions

Here are some useful Node.js functions for AWS SDK v3:

```
const {
  S3Client,
  PutObjectCommand,
  HeadObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

async function createFolder(Bucket, Key) {
  const client = new S3Client();
  const command = new PutObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key });
  return client.send(command);
}

async function existsFolder(Bucket, Key) {
  const client = new S3Client();
  const command = new HeadObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key });

  try {
    await client.send(command);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "NotFound") {
      return false;
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

async function createFolderIfNotExist(Bucket, Key) {
  if (!(await existsFolder(Bucket, Key))) {
    return createFolder(Bucket, Key);
  }
}

async function deleteFolder(Bucket, Key) {
  const client = new S3Client();
  const command = new DeleteObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key });
  return client.send(command);
}
```

Examples of using these functions:

```
const exists1 = await existsFolder("mybucket", "myfolder/");
const exists2 = await existsFolder("mybucket", "pets/dogs/");

if (!exists2) await createFolder("mybucket", "pets/dogs/");
```

### Notes on S3 Object Store

S3 is not your typical file system. It's an object store. It has buckets and objects. Buckets are used to store objects, and objects comprise data (basically a file) and metadata (information about the file). When compared to a traditional file system, it's more natural to think of an S3 bucket as a drive rather than as a folder.

You don't need to pre-create a folder structure in an S3 bucket. You can simply put an object with the key `cars/ford/focus.png` even if `cars/ford/` does not exist.

It's valuable to understand what happens at the API level in this case:

- the [putObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) call will create an object at `cars/ford/focus.png` but it will **not** create anything representing the intermediate folder structure of `cars/` or `cars/ford/`.
- the actual folder structure does not exist, but is implied through `delimiter=/` when you call [listObjects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property), returning folders in `CommonPrefixes` and files in `Contents`.
- you will not be able to test for the ford sub-folder using [headObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) because `cars/ford/` does not actually exist (it is not an object). Instead you have 2 options to see if it (logically) exists:

1. call `listObjects` with prefix=`cars/ford/` and find it in `Contents`
2. call `listObjects` with prefix=`cars/`, delimiter=`/` and find it in `CommonPrefixes`

It is possible to create an S3 object that represents a folder, if you really want to. The AWS S3 console does this, for example. To create myfolder in a bucket named mybucket, you can issue a putObject call with bucket=mybucket, key=myfolder/, and size 0. Note the trailing forward slash.

Here's an example of creating a folder-like object using the awscli:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key cars/ --content-length 0
```

In this case:

- the folder is actually a zero-sized object whose key ends in /.  Note that if you leave off the trailing / then you will get a zero-sized object that appears to be a file rather than a folder.
- you are now able to test for the presence of cars/ in mybucket by issuing a headObject call with bucket=mybucket and key=cars/.

Finally, note that your folder delimiter can be anything you like, for example +, because it is simply part of the key and is not actually a folder separator (there are no folders). You can vary your folder delimiter from listObjects call to call if you like.

Answer (score 33):

The code from @user2837831 doesn't seem to work anymore, probably with the new version of javascript sdk. So I am adding here the version of code that I am using to create a folder inside a bucket using node.js. This works with the 2.1.31 sdk. What is important is the '/' at the end of the Key value in params - using that it thinks you are trying to create a folder and not a file.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var s3Client = new AWS.S3();

var params = { Bucket: 'your_bucket_goes_here', Key: 'folderInBucket/', ACL: 'public-read', Body:'body does not matter' };

s3Client.upload(params, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log("Error creating the folder: ", err);
    } else {
    console.log("Successfully created a folder on S3");

    }
});
```

Comment: HI, Can we put `prefix` on params object so that it can upload at specific folder in the bucket ?

Comment: @MayurKukadiya read the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property). No, you can't supply `Prefix` when calling upload. You simply provide the full `Key`.

Answer (score 12):

This is really straightforward you can do it by using the following, just remember the trailing slash.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = { 
  Bucket: "mybucket", 
  Key: "mykey/"
};

s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 8):

I find that we do not need an explicit directory creation call anymore.

Just the following works for me and automatically creates a directory hierarchy as I need.

```
var userFolder = 'your_bucket_name' + '/' + variable-with-dir-1-name + '/' + variable-with-dir-2-name;
// IMPORTANT : No trailing '/' at the end of the last directory name

AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'YOUR_KEY_HERE',
    secretAccessKey: 'your_secret_access_key_here'
});

var bucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
        Bucket: userFolder
    }
});

var contentToPost = {
    Key: <<your_filename_here>>, 
    Body: <<your_file_here>>,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: <<your_file_content_type>>,
    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
};

bucket.putObject(contentToPost, function (error, data) {

    if (error) {
        console.log("Error in posting Content [" + error + "]");
        return false;
    } /* end if error */
    else {
        console.log("Successfully posted Content");
    } /* end else error */
})
.on('httpUploadProgress',function (progress) {
    // Log Progress Information
    console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100) + '% done');
});
```

Comment: FYI you never needed to explicitly create the folder hierarchy.

Answer (score -2):

In console, the link generated first would be the bucket created path and second would be the folder structure.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var path = require('path')


// Set the region

AWS.config.update({

  region: "us-east-2",

  accessKeyId: "your aws  acces id ",

  secretAccessKey: "your secret access key"
});

s3 = new AWS.S3();

var bucketParams = {

  Bucket: "imageurrllll",

  ACL: "public-read"
};



s3.createBucket(bucketParams, function(err, data) {

  if (err) {

    console.log("Error", err);

  } else {

    console.log("Success", data.Location);

    var folder_name = 'root_folder'

    //this is for local folder data path

    var filePath = "./public/stylesheets/user.png"

    //var child_folder='child'

    var date = Date.now()

    var imgData = `${folder_name}_${date}/` +

      path.basename(filePath);


    var params = {

      Bucket: 'imageurrllll',

      Body: '', //here you can  give image data url from your local directory

      Key: imgData,

      ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    //in this section we are creating the folder structre 

    s3.upload(params, async function(err, aws_uploaded_url) {

      //handle error

      if (err) {

        console.log("Error", err);

      }

      //success
      else {

        console.log("Data Uploaded in:", aws_uploaded_url.Location)

      }

    })
  }

});
```