# How to delete the only files (image) located inside the folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I want to delete the files which is located inside `myfolder` folder in Amazon S3.

*I don't want to delete the folder*

This is the code which I have already tried but it is **not working.**

```
async function deleteFiles(req, res, next) {
    const folderName = req.params.imagesFolder;

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const params = {
        Bucket: config.s3bucket,
        Delete: { 
            Objects: [ 
              {
                Key: `${folderName}/*`
              }
            ],
          },
    }


    console.log(`Params : ${params}`);

    try {
        await s3.headObject(params).promise()
        console.log("File Found in S3")
        try {
            await s3.deleteObject(params).promise()
            console.log("files deleted Successfully");
            next();
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("ERROR in file Deleting : " + JSON.stringify(err));
            res.status.JSON({success:0, message: `ERROR in file Deleting`, error: JSON.stringify(err)});
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("File not Found ERROR : " + err.code);
        res.status(400).json({success:0, message: `File not found`, error: JSON.stringify(err)});
    }
}
```

I'm getting this console error:

`File not Found ERROR : MultipleValidationErrors`

*But the file is present. Even it have image files 3*

response from the server

```
{
    "success": 0,
    "message": "File not found",
    "error": "{\"message\":\"There were 2 validation errors:\\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params\\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Delete' found in params\",\"code\":\"MultipleValidationErrors\",\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Missing required key 'Key' in params\",\"code\":\"MissingRequiredParameter\",\"time\":\"2019-04-01T09:04:22.640Z\"},{\"message\":\"Unexpected key 'Delete' found in params\",\"code\":\"UnexpectedParameter\",\"time\":\"2019-04-01T09:04:22.641Z\"}],\"time\":\"2019-04-01T09:04:22.642Z\"}"
}
```

Any kind help will much appreciated.

Comment: This link might be useful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854114/aws-s3-how-to-delete-all-contents-of-a-directory-in-a-bucket-but-not-the-direct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing there is no folder in your S3 bucket it's just a prefix for your files.

try like this :

```
  var params = {
    Bucket: 'bucketName',
    Prefix: 'myfolder/'
  };

  s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return  console.log(err);

    params = {Bucket: bucketName};
    params.Delete = {Objects:[]};

    data.Contents.forEach(function(content) {
      params.Delete.Objects.push({Key: content.Key});
    });

    s3.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log('well done!');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Abderrahim but the folder `myfolder` is present inside my bucket

Comment: I know there is a "folder" `myfolder` inside your bucket but for S3 service is not a physical folder it's just a prefix to your files just apply the code below and give me a feedback

Comment: The above code worked like a charm but even `myfolder` itself get vanished.

Comment: I got your point `myfolder` is just a prefix is there any way to preserve that folder?

Comment: Actually no but you can ensure that when you put your file into S3 that are named like this : `myfolder + key`

Answer (score 1):

Folders do not exist in Amazon S3. Sort of.

For example, you could create an object with a Key of:

```
folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

This would instantly "create" `folder1` and `folder2`. However, if you were then to delete `foo.txt`, the folders would disappear. This is because the folders do not actually exist — the system just makes them 'appear to exist'. They are officially called **common prefixes** rather than folders.

You *can* create a folder by creating a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. This will cause the folder to "appear" even if there are no objects "in" the folder. But, in general, this isn't necessary. There is very little reason to require an empty folder.